# Bootstrap carousel isn't full width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

i am just building an website and i am curently struggeling with the Bootstraps Carousel it is not filling the whole width of my screen....
Does anyone know how to fix this
Thanks for your answers 
(BTW. there are some things in the code who arn't used yet)

```css
body
{
background-color: black;
}
#Haupt
{
  color: yellow;
    align-content: center;
}

.header1
{

}
h1
{
}
/* The navigation bar */
.navbar {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    position: fixed; /* Set the navbar to fixed position */
    top: 0; /* Position the navbar at the top of the page */
 
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
}

/* Links inside the navbar */
.navbar a {
    
    display: block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* Main content */
.main {
    margin-top: 30px; /* Add a top margin to avoid content overlay */
}
h1:hover
{
    background-color: dimgray;
}

 .tales {
  width: 100%;
}
.carousel-inner{
  width:100%;
  max-height: 200px !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<style>
body {margin:0;}
 
.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.main {
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  height: 1500px; /* Used in this example to enable scrolling */
}

</style>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="navbar">
  <a  href="#home">Home</a>
  <a  href="#news">News</a>
  <a  href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a  href="#about">About</a>
 
</div>

 
 
 
<div class="container">
  <h2>Carousel Example</h2>  
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="Bild1.jpg" alt="Pic1" width = "100%">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="Bild2.jpg" alt="Pic2" width = "100%">
      </div>
    
      <div class="item">
        <img src="Bild3.jpg" alt="Pic3" width = "100%">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

 
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `.container` with `.container-fluid`

Answer (score 0):

Please add the following class next to   as

`.screen-width{
 min-height: 768px !important;
 min-width: 1366px !important;
}`

You can update the Height and Width based on your need. thank you.